# TLS: could not load verify locations

Tags: windows, ssl, ldap, openssl, openldap

I am trying to contact the organization's OpenLDAP server over SSL.

I am not sure if I am trying with the correct certificate, but I am using a `.pfx` file I found.

It is located at `C:/cert/mycert.pfx`

On my `ldap.conf` file I have the following:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
TLS_CACERT C:\\cert\\mycert.pfx
```

When I try to contact the LDAP server I get the following error:

```
TLS: could not load verify locations (file:`C:\\CERT\\mycert.pfx',dir:`')
```

Not sure why the quotes look like that, and also the `dir` is empty and looks like it takes the entire string as the filename and not the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I tried more variations, same error:

`TLS_CACERT C:/cert/mycert.pfx`,

`TLS_CACERT C:\cert\mycert.pfx`

Comment: `I am not sure if I am trying with the correct certificate`. You don't need a certificate. Your LDAP server needs a certificate. Also, a CA certificate is *never* distributed in a PFX. It would be a certificate with only the public key (.CRT).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which TLS you are using on windows. Below section are from documentation, You can try adding `TLS_CACERTDIR <path>` parameter before to test.

```
   TLS_CACERT <filename>
          Specifies  the  file  that  contains certificates for all of the
          Certificate Authorities the client will recognize.

   TLS_CACERTDIR <path>
          Specifies the path of  a  directory  that  contains  Certificate
          Authority   certificates   in  separate  individual  files.  The
          TLS_CACERT is always used before TLS_CACERTDIR.  This  parameter
          is ignored with GnuTLS.
```